# Symfony2 Composer post-install-cmd

Tags: symfony, composer-php, post-update, post-install

I need to install an symfony2 bundle over the composer and do some stuff after the install process. So for the "stuff" after the install i add one line to the "post-install-cmd" in the composer.json

```
ServiceBundle\\Core\\Platform::registerService
```

and it calls the function, everything fine

```
    public static function registerService(Event $event) {
       //some stuff
       exit;
    }
```

The command I use:

```
php composer.phar update serviceplatform/bundles/poll
```

Now my question:
Is it possible to get the name "serviceplatform/bundles/poll" or pass any arguments to the statement? I need the path from the bundle after the install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extra` node is what you're looking for - https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra

In your `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "your-parameter": "serviceplatform/bundles/poll"
}
```

Then, in your `ServiceBundle\Core\Platform::registerService`:

```
public static function registerService(Event $event) 
{
    $extras = $event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getExtra();
    $yourParameter = $extras['your-parameter'];
    //do your stuff
}
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: Okay. That should work..but i need a dynamic parameter. Means php composer.phar update serviceplatform/bundles/poll has parameter poll and php composer.phar update serviceplatform/bundles/test has parameter test. Is there a diffrent way or is the only way to change the parameter before every php composer.phar update